# no phpmyadmin files in /etc

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian

I installed *phpMyAdmin* on **debian 7**.
I downloaded the .tar.gz file and installed it in **var/www**.
*phpMyAdmin* is now accessible trough **myserveurIP**/phpmyadmin.

I would like to access the

```
   /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

file to be able to follow this tutorial: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/securing-your-apache-phpmyadmin-installation/ to change the alias path and restrict access to certain domains.

But i cant find any trace of **phpMyAdmin** in **/etc**. I only find some files related to  phpMyAdmin in

```
   var/www/phpmyadmin
```

and they are nearly all **php** files.

Where can I find these conf files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config files mentioned in the tutorial are Apache HTTP server config files, and they are usually stored in `/etc/apache2/`. You could create such a `phpmyadmin.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`. Alternatively, you could edit the main config file at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Don't forget to reload/restart Apache after making changes.

I assume the authors of the tutorial themselves placed this Apache config file in the mentioned directory; phpMyAdmin is only configured through PHP files residing in the web directory (which you placed inside `/var/www`).

Comment: thx for help. I edited the etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and added: Alias /dbadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin. This works: phpMyAdmin is accessible trough myserverIP/dbadmin. But it is still accessible trough myserverIP/phpmyadmin.Which probably means that it is somewhere written: Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
but I cant find where to comment it out (it is not in /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php)

Comment: Probably because your toplevel (`/var/www`) is still publicly exposed (default for Apache). Probably the easiest way is to simply rename the `phpmyadmin` directory to `dbadmin`, and get rid of the alias.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial appears to not describe how the authors installed phpMyAdmin in the first place, which is a key part here. There are two ways of telling Apache to serve a particular location or set of files; by an Alias or DocumentRoot (which I would usually call the web root). The authors appear to have used the first method where you used the second.

They have placed the phpMyAdmin files outside of the web root (which is `/var/www/` on your system, it seems), and are using an *Alias* Apache configuration directive to tell Apache to load that location. This is a handy way for package managers (such as dpkg/apt/apititude) to keep the file system tidy, for one thing; they add a small file to `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/` (actually in conf-available, which they then symlink to sites-enabled) which reference the installation directory in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.

Since you've manually uncompressed to `/var/www/phpmyadmin`, it's already in the web root and doesn't need an Alias directive to tell Apache where to find it. Adding an Alias directive would conflict with the files here.

The best solution for you, if you wish to follow the directions you linked to, is to move phpMyAdmin out of `/var/www/` to another location (the Debian-suggested `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` is a good choice) and manually create the Alias directive. The alternative (leaving the files in `/var/www/` means you'd be making changes to the default configuration, which is probably not what you really should be doing.